# How to configure Log4j Multiple Appenders for classes in same package

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Please help to correct the appenders with Threshold of info level to reroute to correct appenders for the classes within a package. Below is the properties file 
   `

```
# Root logger option
    log4j.rootLogger=INFO, ffile, stdout ,sfile    
    # Direct log messages to stdout
    log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
    # Direct log messages to a log file
    log4j.appender.ffile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.ffile.Threshold=ERROR
    log4j.appender.ffile.File=failure.log
    log4j.appender.ffile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.ffile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %c{1}: - %m%n
    # Direct log messages to a log file
    log4j.appender.sfile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.sfile.Threshold=INFO
    log4j.appender.sfile.File=success.log
    log4j.appender.sfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.sfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %c{1}: - %m%n
    #Additivity to stop the mix/repeate of logs in multiple appenders
    log4j.additivity.com.rp.handler.AsynchSeeder=false
    log4j.additivity.com.rp.handler=false
    #Configured logger to route to the appender files. Failing
    log4j.logger.com.rp.handler.AsynchSeeder=ERROR, stdout, ffile
    log4j.logger.com.rp.handler=INFO, stdout, sfile
    #Suppress all low level for open source 3rdparty
    log4j.logger.org.apache=WARN
```

`